# How to trigger window.focus() everytime a trigger.io app is opened on the mobile phone

Tags: jquery, ios, window, focus, trigger.io

I would like to trigger a function everytime the app is started on opened on the mobile phone. I use the window.on 'focus' method to listen to the event whenever the window comes into focus. The script I am using is as follows

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    Fulfilled.start();

    forge.enableDebug();

    $(window).on("focus", function(){ forge.logging.log("focus!"); });
  });
</script>
```

However, I realise that the text 'focus!' was only displayed the very first time i start the app. Subsequently, after closing the app and then opening it again will not trigger the message.

How do I modify this so that the function is triggered everytime someone opens up or starts the app?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about a native app built via Trigger.io, you are looking for event.appResumed:

```
window.forge.event.appResumed.addListener(function() {
  forge.logging.log("focus!");
});
```